# Sorting a dataframe based upon a column's first 8 characters

Tags: dataframe, csv, sorting

I have taken the help of `sort_value()` still didn't got the desired output
My input data is

```
i/p
id  speaker_header         pol  sub
10  gertrude34_1_1         0    0
11  gertrude34_1_2         0    0
33  gertrude32_2_1         0.2  0.2
44  gertrude32_3_1         0    0
79  gertrude34_10_1        0    0
81  gertrude34_11_1       -0.3  0.6
83  gertrude34_12_1        0.1  0.8
84  gertrude34_13_1        0.2  0.3
```

The code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df_final = df.sort_values(by='speaker_header',key=lambda x: x.str.split('__').str[0])
df_final
```

Output we got from the code is

```
id  speaker_header         pol  sub
33  gertrude32_2_1         0.2  0.2
44  gertrude32_3_1         0    0
79  gertrude34_10_1        0    0
81  gertrude34_11_1       -0.3  0.6
83  gertrude34_12_1        0.1  0.8
84  gertrude34_13_1        0.2  0.3
10  gertrude34_1_1         0    0
11  gertrude34_1_2         0    0
```

The desired output is

```
desired o/p
id  speaker_header         pol  sub
33  gertrude32_2_1         0.2  0.2
44  gertrude32_3_1          0   0
10  gertrude34_1_1          0   0
11  gertrude34_1_2          0   0
79  gertrude34_10_1         0   0
81  gertrude34_11_1        -0.3 0.6
83  gertrude34_12_1         0.1 0.8
84  gertrude34_13_1         0.2 0.3
```